# Appending form value to action url - Dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url-routing

I've got a form like this:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/abc/def/gh" method="post">
```

I need to dynamically substitute ***localhost:8080*** with the current hostname.

Something like using - `window.location.hostname`

For example, if the curent hostname on which the code is fired has address as ***192.222.1.333:8080*** then the code should dynamically turn to:

```
<form action="http://192.222.1.333:8080/abc/def/gh" method="post">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost:8080/abc/def/gh" id="action-form" method="post"></form>

    <script>
        var form = document.getElementById("action-form");
        form.action = form.action.replace("localhost:8080", window.location.hostname);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```